# How to use if..else condition in with the help of class in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMebH.png   [https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlHAY.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6hoy.png,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K8nn.png,https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOPbS.png,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZd5I.png, [enter image description here][2] I do have a Questionnaire and answers are in different form such as textbox, radiobuttons, checkboxes or dropdown.
My following code execute the radiobutton loop and select the radio button options then executs checkbox loop and select checkbox and then textbox, 3 individual loops are running but its not a right way to do so. I want to use if..else and to checks whether its radio/check/textbox/select..etc.

```
List<WebElement> radioGroups = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-radio-group[@role='radiogroup']"));
for(int j=0; j<radioGroups.size(); j++)
{
    List<WebElement> radioOptions = radioGroups.get(j).findElements(By.tagName("mat-radio-button"));    
    if (radioOptions.size()>0)
    {   
        Random rnd = new Random();
        WebElement sValue = radioOptions.get(rnd.nextInt(radioOptions.size()));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        act.moveToElement(sValue).click().build().perform();
    }
}


List<WebElement> totalCheckboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//app-mat-checkbox-group"));
WebElement checkBox =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-checkbox/label/div/input"));
    for(int k=0; k<totalCheckboxes.size(); k++)
    {
        List<WebElement> checkboxOption = totalCheckboxes.get(k).findElements(By.tagName("mat-checkbox"));  
        if (checkboxOption.size()>0)
        {   
            Random rnd = new Random();
            WebElement sValue = checkboxOption.get(rnd.nextInt(checkboxOption.size()));
            act.moveToElement(sValue).click().build().perform();
                }
            }
        }

List<WebElement> textboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='input ng-star-inserted']/div/div//div/input"));

    for(int i=0; i<=textboxes.size()-2; i++)
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(textboxes.get(i))); 
        if(textboxes.get(i).isEnabled())
        {
            final String getSaltString = getSaltString();
            textboxes.get(i).sendKeys(getSaltString);}
        }
    }
```

I do have xpath which can be use for if.else

```
//div[@class='answers-container col ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='TextBox']
//div[@class='answers-container col ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='CheckBox']
//div[@class='answers-container col ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='RadioButton']
//div[@class='answers-container col ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='DropDpwnList']
```

OR

```
app-input[@inputtype='text']  
app-radio[@inputtype='radio']  
app-radio[@inputtype='checkbox']  
app-select
```

I tried with,

```
if(!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='answers-container col ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='TextBox']").isEmpty)
    {
       Code of TextBox
    }
```

and same way for other options but it did not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you put screenshot of your webpage to be more clear how it looks or share DOM or url.

Comment: Now is it possible to put the screenshot?

Comment: Yes you can edit your question

Comment: I added but not able to take full html code

Comment: You mean you have a webpage with multiple questions and each question has different answer input types? Or in one question there are different answer Input types?

Comment: Each question has different answer input types, there may be continuous 4-5 questions have input type textbox or radio buttons or checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, actually i am on my phone, but i will try to add answer. Please ignore any spelling or indentation mistake.

Comment: No Problem, sure, if you want more detail related to question please let me know

Comment: It took so much time to write this short code snippet from phone. :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<WebElement> answers = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.answers-container.col.ng-star-inserted div"));

      for(int i = 0;i<answers.size();i++)
      {
          Random rnd = new Random();
          String answerType= answers.get(i).getAttribute("class");
          if(answerType.equals("DropDpwnList"))
          {
              WebElement dropdownOptions = answers.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select-box']/select"));
              Select options=new Select(dropdownOptions);
              int totalOptions= options.getOptions().size();
              options.selectByIndex(rnd.nextInt(totalOptions));

          }
          elseif(answerType.equals("TextBox"))
          { 
              final String getSaltString = getSaltString();
               WebElement textbox = answers.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
              wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(textbox)); 
              textbox.sendKeys(getSaltString);
          }

          elseif(answerType.equals("RadioButton"))
          {
              List<WebElement> radioOptions = answers.get(i)
                      .findElements(By.tagName("mat-radio-button"));
              if(radioOptions.size()>0)
              {
                  WebElement sValue = radioOptions.get(rnd.nextInt(radioOptions.size()));
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                  act.moveToElement(sValue).click().build().perform();
              }}
          elseif(answerType.equals("CheckBox"))
          {
              List<WebElement> checkboxOption = answers.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("mat-checkbox"));
              if(checkboxOption.size()>0)
              {
                  WebElement sValue = checkboxOption.get(rnd.nextInt(checkboxOption.size()));
                  act.moveToElement(sValue).click().build().perform();
              }}
      }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212221/discussion-on-answer-by-mkhurmi-how-to-use-if-else-condition-in-with-the-help-o).

Answer (score 1):

try this- hope this will help.

```
  List<WebElement>totalAnswer = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'answers-container')]");//It will have all elements and now traverse through each element

for(int i=0; i<totalAnswer.size(); i++)
{
Random rnd = new Random();

String webeleTag=totalAnswer.get(i).getAttribute("inputtype");
//you can use switch case as well instead of If else

if (webeleTag.equals("radio")){
List<WebElement> radioOptions = totalAnswer.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("mat-radio-button"));    
    if (radioOptions.size()>0)
    {   
       WebElement sValue = radioOptions.get(rnd.nextInt(radioOptions.size()));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        act.moveToElement(sValue).click().build().perform();
    }

}
else if (webeleTag.equals("checkbox")){
List<WebElement> checkboxOption = totalAnswer.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("mat-checkbox"));  
        if (checkboxOption.size()>0)
        {   

            WebElement sValue = checkboxOption.get(rnd.nextInt(checkboxOption.size()));
            act.moveToElement(sValue).click().build().perform();
                }
            }
        }

}

else if(webeleTag.equals("text")){
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(totalAnswer.get(i))); 
        if(totalAnswer.get(i).isEnabled())
        {
            final String getSaltString = getSaltString();
            textboxes.get(i).sendKeys(getSaltString);}
        }
}
else{
//if you want to add anything here
}
```